# Star formation rate in different galaxies

Tags: astrophysics, simulations, stars, galaxies, stellar-evolution

I was looking for some scale to compare my result of star formation rate and see if it is moderate or high or low. But I couldn't find any scale. Is there any paper related to such scale where Star formation rate from minimum to maximum of each galaxy is given and one can compare his/her result with scale?

I found that one of the dwarf galaxies has a 0.2 star formation rate, but since I don't have a scale to compare, I have no clue whether it is a high or low or moderate star formation rate? What is the maximum star formation rate?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about Astronomy and would be a better fit for [astronomy.se]

Comment: This is an interesting question and I don't know the answer. I do know that Star formation in ellipticals and in lenticulars is low, but I have never heard of a scale relating star formation to galaxy type. Another factor is galaxy age, as most star formation takes place when the galaxy is first formed. It would be a valuable research project to collect and collate star formation rates for large numbers of galaxies and could teach us a lot about galaxy formation and evolution.

Comment: @StephenG I disagree. This is a question of Astrophysics and it is perfectly in topic here. Moreover, see a recent discussion here: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13227/should-we-leave-technical-astronomy-questions-to-astronomy-se